Create column based on many columns and column labels with for loop?
I have a data frame similar to the example data frame below:
stuff = data.frame(
  banana = c(1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1),
  apple = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1),
  bike = c(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0),
  car = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)
)

I would like to create a column that refers to the value of other columns, and if TRUE add the column label to that new column. In the case of adding the column fruits based on the columns banana and apple, ideally resulting in this (I do not care too much about the formatting of there being multiple words, as long as its captured in a consistent order):
> stuff
   banana apple bike car      fruits
1       1     0    1   0      banana
2       0     0    1   0           0
3       1     0    0   0      banana
4       1     1    1   0 bananaapple
5       0     1    1   0       apple
6       0     0    1   0           0
7       1     0    1   1      banana
8       0     1    0   1       apple
9       1     1    0   0 bananaapple
10      1     1    0   0 bananaapple

I have seen this done using mutate in dplyr, however my dataset has many columns and rows so I would need to find a way to do this in a for loop manner, iterating through a vector of column labels and adding the label consecutively to the new column if TRUE. I sloppily attempted to combine a for loop and mutate (as seen below) but this did not work, since it didn't recognize the variable fruit from the for loop:
fruits1 = c('banana','apple')

for (fruit in fruits1){
  stuff %>%
    mutate(fruits = case_when(
      fruit == TRUE ~ fruit,
      FALSE ~ FALSE
    ))
}

I would appreciate any advice about how to do this on a larger scale and execute a similar code.

You could do stuff > 0 which creates a matrix, then apply an intersect on rows (MARGIN=1) and coerce toString.
> apply(stuff > 0, 1, \(x) {
+   o <- intersect(names(stuff)[x], fruits1)
+   if (!length(o)) NA else toString(o)
+ })
 [1] "banana"        NA              "banana"       
 [4] "banana, apple" "apple"         NA             
 [7] "banana"        "apple"         "banana, apple"
[10] "banana, apple"

To add the column you can use transform
> stuff |> transform(fruits1=apply(stuff > 0, 1, \(x) {
+   o <- intersect(names(stuff)[x], fruits1)
+   if (!length(o)) NA else toString(o)
+ }))
   banana apple bike car       fruits1
1       1     0    1   0        banana
2       0     0    1   0          <NA>
3       1     0    0   0        banana
4       1     1    1   0 banana, apple
5       0     1    1   0         apple
6       0     0    1   0          <NA>
7       1     0    1   1        banana
8       0     1    0   1         apple
9       1     1    0   0 banana, apple
10      1     1    0   0 banana, apple

For use with multiple fruit* vectors, put them in a named list and use in sapply, then easily cbind:
> stuff |> 
+   cbind(
+     sapply(list(fruits1=fruits1, fruits2=fruits2, fruits3=fruits3), \(y) {
+       apply(stuff > 0, 1, \(x) {
+         o <- intersect(names(stuff)[x], y)
+         if (!length(o)) NA else toString(o)
+       })
+     })
+   )
   banana apple bike car       fruits1     fruits2           fruits3
1       1     0    1   0        banana        bike      banana, bike
2       0     0    1   0          <NA>        bike              bike
3       1     0    0   0        banana        <NA>            banana
4       1     1    1   0 banana, apple apple, bike      banana, bike
5       0     1    1   0         apple apple, bike              bike
6       0     0    1   0          <NA>        bike              bike
7       1     0    1   1        banana        bike banana, bike, car
8       0     1    0   1         apple       apple               car
9       1     1    0   0 banana, apple       apple            banana
10      1     1    0   0 banana, apple       apple            banana


Data:
> dput(stuff)
structure(list(banana = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), apple = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), bike = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0), car = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
> dput(fruits1)
c("banana", "apple")
> dput(fruits2)
c("bike", "apple")
> dput(fruits3)
c("bike", "banana", "car")


Here's a tidyverse approach, first putting the vectors to match against in a named list.
things <- list(a = c("banana", "apple"),
               b = c("car", "bike", "apple"))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(stuff %>% mutate(id = row_number()), -id) %>% 
  mutate(purrr::map_dfr(things, ~ {.x[match(name, .x)] %>% replace_na("")})) %>% 
  mutate(across(-c(name, value), ~ paste(if_else(value == 0, "", .x), collapse="")),
         .by = id) %>% 
  pivot_wider()

output
# A tibble: 10 × 7
      id a             b           banana apple  bike   car
   <int> <chr>         <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 "banana"      "bike"           1     0     1     0
 2     2 ""            "bike"           0     0     1     0
 3     3 "banana"      ""               1     0     0     0
 4     4 "bananaapple" "applebike"      1     1     1     0
 5     5 "apple"       "applebike"      0     1     1     0
 6     6 ""            "bike"           0     0     1     0
 7     7 "banana"      "bikecar"        1     0     1     1
 8     8 "apple"       "applecar"       0     1     0     1
 9     9 "bananaapple" "apple"          1     1     0     0
10    10 "bananaapple" "apple"          1     1     0     0


The pmap family from purrr is also straightforward and produces the desired output:
    stuff %>% 
      mutate(fruits=pmap_chr(across(c(1:2))
     , ~ str_c(names(c(...)[which(c(...) > 0)]) ,collapse = ""))) %>% 
      mutate(across(fruits, ~ replace(., . == '', "0")))

output:
   banana apple bike car      fruits
1       1     0    1   0      banana
2       0     0    1   0           0
3       1     0    0   0      banana
4       1     1    1   0 bananaapple
5       0     1    1   0       apple
6       0     0    1   0           0
7       1     0    1   1      banana
8       0     1    0   1       apple
9       1     1    0   0 bananaapple
10      1     1    0   0 bananaapple


You can try
transform(
  stuff,
  fruits = apply(
    stuff[fruits1],
    1,
    \(x) ifelse(all(x == 0), 0, toString(fruits1[x]))
  )
)

which gives
   banana apple bike car         fruits
1       1     0    1   0         banana
2       0     0    1   0              0
3       1     0    0   0         banana
4       1     1    1   0 banana, banana
5       0     1    1   0         banana
6       0     0    1   0              0
7       1     0    1   1         banana
8       0     1    0   1         banana
9       1     1    0   0 banana, banana
10      1     1    0   0 banana, banana


or
within(
  stuff,
  fruits <- apply(
    stuff[fruits1],
    1,
    \(x) fruits1[x]
  )
)

which gives
   banana apple bike car         fruits
1       1     0    1   0         banana
2       0     0    1   0
3       1     0    0   0         banana
4       1     1    1   0 banana, banana
5       0     1    1   0         banana
6       0     0    1   0
7       1     0    1   1         banana
8       0     1    0   1         banana
9       1     1    0   0 banana, banana
10      1     1    0   0 banana, banana

